# SQL View based on a xml column

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2012, xquery

My problem is to build a SQL view based on a XML column.

My current table has two columns. One for timestamp and second for data.
The data-column is from XML datatype and the content is:

```
<data>
    <entry header ="Parameter1" value="1" type="System.Boolean"/>
    <entry header ="Parameter2" value="0" type="System.Boolean"/>
    <entry header ="Parameter3" value="140" type="System.int16"/>
    <entry header ="Parameter4" value="80" type="System.int16"/>
    <entry header ="Parameter5" value="530602-455605" type="System.String"/>
</data>
```

Now I want to create following view:

```
Timestamp           | Parameter1 | Parameter 2 | Parameter 3 | Parameter 4 | Parameter 5
--------------------+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+---------------------
2016-10-24 11:30:00 |     1      |      0      |     140     |     80      | 530602-455605
```

How can I do this?

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    Timestamp 
    Par1... 
    Par2...
    ParN... 
FROM 
    TableName 
ORDER BY 
    Timestamp DESC
```

Thanks in advance!

## Update

I got the following result (sorry for format):

```
Timestamp               Header  Value   ValueType

2016-10-24 08:00:00.000 Abguss1 1   System.Boolean

2016-10-24 08:00:00.000 Abguss  0   System.Boolean

2016-10-24 08:00:00.000 Abgussgewicht   140 System.int16

2016-10-24 08:00:00.000 Stopfen 80  System.int16

2016-10-24 08:00:00.000 Werkzeug    530602-455605   System.String

2016-10-24 08:00:20.000 Abguss1 1   System.Boolean

2016-10-24 08:00:20.000 Abguss  0   System.Boolean

2016-10-24 08:00:20.000 Abgussgewicht   138 System.int16

2016-10-24 08:00:20.000 Stopfen 80  System.int16

2016-10-24 08:00:20.000 Werkzeug    530602-455605   System.String

2016-10-24 08:00:40.000 Abguss1 1   System.Boolean

2016-10-24 08:00:40.000 Abguss  0   System.Boolean

2016-10-24 08:00:40.000 Abgussgewicht   178 System.int16

2016-10-24 08:00:40.000 Stopfen 80  System.int16

2016-10-24 08:00:40.000 Werkzeug    530602-455605   System.String

2016-10-24 08:01:20.000 Abguss1 1   System.Boolean

2016-10-24 08:01:20.000 Abguss  0   System.Boolean

2016-10-24 08:01:20.000 Abgussgewicht   158 System.int16

2016-10-24 08:01:20.000 Stopfen 80  System.int16

2016-10-24 08:01:20.000 Werkzeug    530602-455605   System.String

2016-10-24 08:01:43.000 Abguss1 1   System.Boolean

2016-10-24 08:01:43.000 Abguss  0   System.Boolean

2016-10-24 08:01:43.000 Abgussgewicht   162 System.int16

2016-10-24 08:01:43.000 Stopfen 80  System.int16

2016-10-24 08:01:43.000 Werkzeug    530602-455605   System.String
```

Comment: The tag `sql` is not enough. This is highly vendor specific stuff... Please provide vendor and version of your RDBMS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT, YourTime DATETIME, YourData XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(1,GETDATE(),N'<data>
                                        <entry header ="Parameter1" value="1" type="System.Boolean"/>
                                        <entry header ="Parameter2" value="0" type="System.Boolean"/>
                                        <entry header ="Parameter3" value="140" type="System.int16"/>
                                        <entry header ="Parameter4" value="80" type="System.int16"/>
                                        <entry header ="Parameter5" value="530602-455605" type="System.String"/>
                                    </data>');
SELECT ID 
      ,YourTime
      ,YourData.value('(/data/entry[@header="Parameter1"]/@value)[1]','bit') AS Param1
      ,YourData.value('(/data/entry[@header="Parameter2"]/@value)[1]','bit') AS Param2
      ,YourData.value('(/data/entry[@header="Parameter3"]/@value)[1]','int') AS Param3
      ,YourData.value('(/data/entry[@header="Parameter4"]/@value)[1]','int') AS Param4
      ,YourData.value('(/data/entry[@header="Parameter5"]/@value)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Param5
FROM @tbl
```

### UPDATE

Obviously there is a problem with your data... Try the following statement to find all `<entry>`-elements and try to find, which one disturbs the reading process...

```
SELECT ID --or TimeStamp-Column or any other row-defining column
      ,e.value('@header','nvarchar(max)') AS Header
      ,e.value('@value','nvarchar(max)') AS Value
      ,e.value('@type','nvarchar(max)') AS ValueType
FROM YourTable
CROSS APPLY YourData.nodes('/data/entry') AS A(e)
```

My code for reading will pick the value of the entry with the given header name  and cast this to the given target type. As long - as you tell me - the *long number with the hyphen* is sitting in "Parameter5" there cannot be a cast error with `bit`...

### UPDATE 2

Your posted example data shows clearly, that your XML is not called `Parameter1` to `Parameter5` but with german words. Try it like this:

```
SELECT ID 
      ,YourTime
      ,YourData.value('(/data/entry[@header="Abguss1"]/@value)[1]','bit') AS Abguss1
      ,YourData.value('(/data/entry[@header="Abguss"]/@value)[1]','bit') AS Abguss
      ,YourData.value('(/data/entry[@header="Abgussgewicht"]/@value)[1]','int') AS Abgussgewicht
      ,YourData.value('(/data/entry[@header="Stopfen"]/@value)[1]','int') AS Stopfen
      ,YourData.value('(/data/entry[@header="Werkzeug"]/@value)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Werkzeug
FROM YourTable
```

Ich wünsche viel Glück beim Lösen der Aufgabe :-)

Comment: Thank you, but I still got the Error Message "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '530602-455605' to data type bit." if I create my view with this statement.

Comment: @K.M. This might happen, if your value `530602-455605` is not at `header="Parameter5"` Parameter 1 and 2 are read as `bit`, 3 and 4 as `int` and 5 as `nvarchar(max)`. This is following your given example...

Comment: But it is always at Header="Parameter5". If I only select Parameter1 there is always the error for "530602-455605"...

Comment: @K.M. Just for testing: Try to set all target types to `nvarchar(max)`. If this  works I promise you, that there must be at least one line where this data is  found with `Paramter 1 or 2`...

Comment: The test was successfull. But there is no line with this data in Parameter1. It is always the value "1".

Comment: Dann können wir ja auf deutsch kommunizieren! Zunächst nochmal vielen Dank. Ich war natürlich nicht ganz so doof und habe vorher die entsprechenden Spaltennamen angepasst. Der Fehler kommt trotzdem noch.

Comment: @K.M. Die Sprach auf SO ist Englisch und deshalb bleibe ich mal dabei... Turn your approach to find the error *up-side-down*: Set all to `nvarchar(max)` and find out which line produces a **non-bit-value** at "Abguss1" or "Abguss". If this is not the only statement it could be, that your problem is elsewhere... I assure you, that this code must work... as long as the data is clean...

Comment: Now I know what the problem was, if you set the property for Data column to do not allow nulls, this error message will come.

Comment: @K.M. I must admit, that this explanation does not really fit to the problem as I've understood this... Nvm, glad that you could solve this! If my answer solved your issue it would be kind to tick the acceptance check below the vote counter. Thx und frohes Coden!